# Asp.Net Core 2.0 and Webpack - Module build failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.0"

Tags: c#, npm, webpack, babeljs, asp.net-core-2.0

We have a rather large ASP.Net Core 2.0 application and for standardization with other projects, have chosen to migrate to Webpack in place of Gulp. What I am trying to do is build a react component out of several files. The 'require' statement chain begins in group-list-entrypoint.js, which has been set as the Entry for Webpack. So first up, the webpack.config.js file:

```
var createReactGroupListTable = {
mode: 'development',
devtool: 'source-map',
entry: {
    group_list_table: "./scripts/project/group-list-entrypoint.js"
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/lib/react'),
    filename: "[name].js"
},
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.js?$/, use: { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'] } } }
        ]
}
};
module.exports = [ createReactGroupListTable ];
```

Next, package.json:

```
{
"name": "-",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
"npm": "^5.8.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.44",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.44",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.44",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
"css-loader": "^0.28.11",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
"react": "^16.3.1",
"react-dom": "^16.3.1",
"style-loader": "^0.20.3",
"url-loader": "^1.0.1",
"webpack": "^4.5.0",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"wbp": "webpack"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

And of course the problem I need help with - npm reporting 
Module build failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.0". I'll also provide the stack trace:

```
 ERROR in ./scripts/project/group-list-entrypoint.js
Module build failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.0". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing preset: "C:\\Users\\pan.sotnik\\source\\repos\\Project\\Project\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-react\\lib\\index.js")
    at throwVersionError (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:64:11)
    at Object.assertVersion (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:13:11)
    at C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\@babel\preset-react\lib\index.js:71:7
    at C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:18:12
    at C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:317:46
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
    at new File (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:50:20)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\Users\pan.sotnik\source\repos\Project\Project\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:173:20)
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `babel-loader` uses babel 6. You need the pre-released `"8.x"` version to use babel 7.

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#install